# How do I dynamically change the title of React Native stack navigation screens?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

I'm using stack navigation for a React Native app, and I want to dynamically change the title of a screen when you go to it from another screen.

My navigation is set up as follows in `App.js`:

```
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    ResultDetails: ResultDetailsScreen
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        title: 'App Name'
    }
});
```

On the `HomeScreen`, I have a `FlatList` of `TouchableOpacity` elements that link to the `ResultDetailsScreen` as follows:

```
<FlatList
    data={results}
    keyExtractor={ (result) => result.id }
    renderItem={ ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('ResultDetails', item) }
            >
                <Text>{ item.name }</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    } }
/>
```

The `item` I'm sending to the `ResultDetailsScreen` has both `id` and `name` properties.

How do I take the `name` property of `item` and dynamically set that for the stack navigation title on the `ResultDetailsScreen`? I've looked at related topics on SO, etc., but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've seen some stuff about maybe using the following:

```
navigation.setParams({
    title: 'New Title'
});
```

But when I do that, I don't see `New Title` on the `ResultDetailsScreen`, and for whatever reason, I can no longer go back in the app.

Lastly, if it makes a difference, I'm using functions and hooks, not classes for my React Native code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a static function in which screen you have to set dynamic name

```js
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        navOptions = navigation
        return {
            title: 'Notification',
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

When using functions for React Native components instead of classes, you have to do the following:

First, send the data you want to use for the page title to the page using `navigation.navigate`. For example:

```
<FlatList
    data={results}
    keyExtractor={ (result) => result.id }
    renderItem={ ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('ResultDetails', {
                    name: item.name
                }) }
            >
                <Text>{ item.name }</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    } }
/>
```

Then, on the page itself, you can add `navigationOptions` as a property of the screen function as follows:

```
const ResultDetailsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    // Return your view here like you always do.
};

// Add this.
// Do this to get the name property to be dynamically set for the page title.
ResultDetailsScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const name = navigation.getParam('name');

    return {
        title: name
    };
};

export default ResultDetailsScreen;
```